# Connecting a sink of BLoC with another BLoC

Tags: dart, flutter

I am using the BLoC pattern as described at [the Google IO talk](https://medium.com/flutter-io/build-reactive-mobile-apps-in-flutter-companion-article-13950959e381).

I have a simple BLoC which is used to display a alert in the UI whenever a string is added to `messageSink`:

```
class AlertBloc {
  final _message = BehaviorSubject<String>();

  AlertBloc() {}

  Stream<String> get message => _message.stream;

  Sink<String> get messageSink => _message.sink;

  void dispose() {
    _message.close();   }
}
```

Elsewhere in the app, I have another BLoC which needs to add a string to `messageSink`, when a certain condition is met.

I noticed it is not a good idea to provide the whole BLoC from the [Google I/O repo for the talk](https://github.com/filiph/state_experiments/blob/master/shared/lib/src/bloc_complex/product_grid/product_square_bloc.dart), and they provide advice for connecting a **stream** from a BLoC to another BLoC **sink**:

> Note that we are *not* providing [CartBloc] to the
>   [ProductSquareBloc] directly, although it would be easier to
>   implement. BLoCs should not depend on other BLoCs (separation of
>   concerns). They can only communicate with each other using
>   streams. In this case, the [CartBloc.items] output plugs into the
>   [ProductSquareBloc.cartItems] input.

My question is how to connect a **sink** from a BLoC to another BLoC **stream**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example for you. Imagine the following two BLoCs:

The first one exposes a `Stream` and populates it with some values:

```
class ProducerBLoC {

    //Controller is private - you do not want to expose it
    final StreamController<int> _productionController = StreamController<int>();
    //Instead, you expose a stream
    Stream<int> get production => _productionController.stream;

    //This method generates some values and puts them to stream
    void produceValue() {
        _productionController.sink.add(1);
        _productionController.sink.add(2);
        _productionController.sink.add(3);
    }

    //Don't forget to close your controllers
    void dispose() {
      _productionController.close();
    }
}
```

The other one exposes a `Sink` and processes values that are put into it.

```
class ConsumerBLoC {

    //Controller is private - you do not want to expose it
    final StreamController<int> _consumptionController = StreamController<int>();
    //Instead, you expose a sink
    StreamSink<int> get consumption => _consumptionController.sink;

    //In class constructor we start listening to the stream of values
    ConsumerBLoC() {
       _consumptionController.listen((value) {_consumeValue(value);} );
       //or simply: _consumptionController.listen(_consumeValue); //theese are the same
    }

    //This method generates some values and puts them to stream
    void consumeValue(int value) {
         //Do something with the value
         print('Value processed: $value');
    }

    //Don't forget to close your controllers
    void dispose() {
      _consumptionController.close();
    }
}
```

Now, the task is to connect production stream to consumption sink. As you have correctly noticed, you do not want for any of two BLoCs to *know* anything about existence of the other one. So none of the two should hold references to the other one or even create instances of another one. Instead, you connect them using your `Widget` class:

```
//Define some widget to represent main screen of your application
class MainScreen extends StatefulWidget {

   @override
   State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _MainScreenState();
}

//And define a state for this widget (state does not need to be public)
class _MainScreenState extends State<MainScreen> {

    //You define both blocks here
    ProducerBLoC _producer = new ProducerBLoC();
    ConsumerBLoC _consumer = new ConsumerBLoC();

    //Now, either do it in _MainScreenState constructor, or in the initState() method
    @override
    void initState() {
        super.initState();

        //Connect production stream with consumption sink
        _producer.production.listen((value) => _consumer.consumption.add(value));
        //Or, beautifully: _producer.production.pipe(_consumer.consumption);
    }

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        //The exact implementation does not matter in current context
    }

    //And don't forget to close your controllers
    @override
    dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        _producer.dispose();
        _consumer.dispose();
    }

}
```

This way, any value generated by `ProducerBLoC` will immediately be consumed by `ConsumerBLoC`. And, what's the most important, - both BLoCs are completely independent from one another!

Answer (score 0):

The exact same way as you'd do with streams: Passing it as parameter

```
class Bloc {
  final Sink<int> _external;

  Bloc(this._external);
}
```

Comment: This is not a good thing to do. It is much better for `Bloc` to expose its own `Stream` of values instead of _grabbing_ someone else's `Sink` and putting values into it.